# how to pass parameters to const value in intel SSE intrinsics?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics

I know the use of **const value** in arguments ; when you don't want the function to modify the parameter.

So this test code is running well :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void foo (const int y ) 
{
    printf ( "x = %d \n" , y*2 ) ;  
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int y = 3;
    foo ( y );
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

But when I was doing the same on intel SSE intrinsics for example *_mm_blend_epi16* function, I get this error :

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
```

The code for this error was :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <io.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int y = 3 ;
    __m128i x1,x2;
    _mm_blend_epi16(x1,x2,y);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

And the **_mm_blend_epi16** definition is :

```
__m128i _mm_blend_epi16( __m128i a, __m128i b, const int mask )
```

So, What is the problem ? Am I doing something wrong ?

**EDIT**
**And what's is the solution ?**

Comment: Note that this does work with gcc (tested with gcc 4.5.2 and gcc 4.8.2). Fails with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: @ScottD the first code is running well in visual c++ 2012. 
the problem is in the second code that gives me the above error

Comment: I understand. I was just pointing out that this problem is specific to Microsoft compilers and not C or C++ compilers in general. That is, the second code works with gcc.

Comment: It is not possible to do what you want - `mask` param is an immediate operand - that means that it is a part of a instruction and must be known at the compile time. If you need a separate function that calls _mm_blend_epi16 with a mask as argument, you'll have to implement it as a macro and write code like `const int mask = 3` everywhere. Or you can use similar instruction `_mm_blendv_epi8` that shuffles 8-bit words and doesn't require mask to be compile-time constant (note that it has to be slightly different that a mask for `_mm_blend_epi16`.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `_mm_blend_epi16` requires mask not only to be `const int`, but to be a known value at the compile time (like `constexpr` in c++11). So, even `_mm_blend_epi16(x1,x2,(const int)y)` won't work. This behavior differs from the one from test example, because it is a compiler intrinsic and not a real function.

Comment: Hi! You write good answers in terms of content, but please read the formatting FAQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a work around that may be useful. Limitations: The desired efficient code generation is present only with a release (optimized) build. If the compiler cannot figure out the mask value, no error message is logged. Instead you will get inefficient code generation. Therefore the code generation must be inspected using a debugger or disassembler to confirm the desired result. This work around requires calling a wrapper function in place of _mm_blend_epi16 itself. The optimizer will inline a single _mm_blend_epi16 in its place. Here is an example using plain C code. Tested with Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "smmintrin.h"

#define XM(a,b,x) if (mask == x) result = _mm_blend_epi16 (a, b, x)
#define XM1(a,b,x) XM (a,b,x+0x00); XM (a,b,x+0x01); XM (a,b,x+0x02); XM (a,b,x+0x03);\
                   XM (a,b,x+0x04); XM (a,b,x+0x05); XM (a,b,x+0x06); XM (a,b,x+0x07);\
                   XM (a,b,x+0x08); XM (a,b,x+0x09); XM (a,b,x+0x0A); XM (a,b,x+0x0B);\
                   XM (a,b,x+0x0C); XM (a,b,x+0x0D); XM (a,b,x+0x0E); XM (a,b,x+0x0F);

static __m128i my_mm_blend_epi16(__m128i a, __m128i b, int mask)
    {
    __m128i result;
    XM1 (a, b, 0x00); XM1 (a, b, 0x10); XM1 (a, b, 0x20); XM1 (a, b, 0x30);
    XM1 (a, b, 0x40); XM1 (a, b, 0x50); XM1 (a, b, 0x60); XM1 (a, b, 0x70);
    XM1 (a, b, 0x80); XM1 (a, b, 0x90); XM1 (a, b, 0xa0); XM1 (a, b, 0xb0);
    XM1 (a, b, 0xc0); XM1 (a, b, 0xd0); XM1 (a, b, 0xe0); XM1 (a, b, 0xf0);
    return result;
    }

int main(void)
    {
    int y = 0x99;
    __m128i x1,x2;

    x1 =_mm_set_epi32 (1, 2, 3, 4);
    x2 =_mm_set_epi32 (5, 6, 7, 8);
    x2 = my_mm_blend_epi16 (x1, x2, y);

    printf ("%x\n", _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (x2));
    return 0;
    }
```

Here is a release build debugger view that shows the code generation:

```
int main(void)
    {
00161000 55                   push        ebp  
00161001 8B EC                mov         ebp,esp  
00161003 83 E4 F8             and         esp,0FFFFFFF8h  
    int y = 0x99;
    __m128i x1,x2;

    x1 =_mm_set_epi32 (1, 2, 3, 4);
00161006 66 0F 6F 05 00 21 16 00 movdqa      xmm0,xmmword ptr ds:[162100h]  
    x2 =_mm_set_epi32 (5, 6, 7, 8);
0016100E 66 0F 6F 0D 10 21 16 00 movdqa      xmm1,xmmword ptr ds:[162110h]  
    x2 = my_mm_blend_epi16 (x1, x2, y);
00161016 66 0F 3A 0E C1 99    pblendw     xmm0,xmm1,99h  

    printf ("%x\n", _mm_cvtsi128_si32 (x2));
0016101C 66 0F 7E C0          movd        eax,xmm0  
00161020 50                   push        eax  
00161021 68 F4 20 16 00       push        offset string "%x\n" (1620F4h)  
00161026 FF 15 A0 20 16 00    call        dword ptr [__imp__printf (1620A0h)]  
0016102C 83 C4 08             add         esp,8  
    return 0;
0016102F 33 C0                xor         eax,eax  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

the intrinsic

```
__m128i _mm_blend_epi16( __m128i a, __m128i b, const int mask
```

expects the third parameter to be a const int; so a const value which is known at compile time.

if you modify the code like:

```
    const int y = 3 ;
    _mm_blend_epi16(x1,x2,y);
```

if should work.

Alternatively, use a `#define` for mask